# Laplace transform of noncentral chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

I'm interested in non central chi-square distribution. More specifically, i want to derive the laplace transform of noncentral chi-sqruae disribution or density function.

Let me know whether it exists or relevent book and paper.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the definition of the non-central chi-square distribution? That'll make your question more accessible.

Comment: You can get this off the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution by noting that the Laplace transform is $E[e^{-s X}]$. This has the same form as the mgf $E[e^{t X}]$ and the mgf is given on the wiki page, so simply replace $t$ with $-s$ there.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the probability function for the chi-square distribution with $r$ degrees of freedom 
$$P_r(x)=\frac{x^{-1+r/2}e^{-x/2}}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}$$
The Laplace transform is :
$$\int_0^\infty P_r(x)e^{-sx}dx = \frac{(s+1/2)^{-r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}= (2s+1)^{-r/2}$$

Comment: That's not the **noncentral** chi-square

Comment: Also it can't be right: $\Gamma(-r/2)$ will be undefined at all even positive integers $r$.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple, I find the Laplace transform of the noncentral chi-square density with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\delta$ is

$$  \left( 1+2\,s \right) ^{-\nu/2} \exp\left(-{\frac  {\delta\,s}{1+2\,s}}\right)
$$

Answer (score -1):

It is mentioned in the following paper:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02595410